# sobre conjuntos en Typescript

Tags: typescript

¿Alguien sabe si en typescript existe un operador de conjuntos como el in de Delphi?
Explico, en Delphi puedo saber si el valor de una variable está entre los valores de un conjunto.
if (variable in [1,2,3,5,7]) then (en delphi como ver si variable tiene un valor primo < 10)
¿Cómo sería en Typescript?
Quiero saber si una variable con un estado no sea de cualquiera 3 estados diferentes para hacer algo.

Comment: Puedes usar el includes para saber si una variable, por ejemplo: `[1,2,3,5,7].includes(1)` esto retornara `true`

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar. Traté de hacer algo parecido [1,3,5,7].has(1) pero es de conjuntos, no de arrays

Comment: Pero si en tu pregunta dices que deseas algo como el operador `in` de Delphi, que aplica a Conjuntos, entonces lo que debes definir es un Conjunto en Javascript (Set) y no un Array. Así ya estarías aplicando la misma estructura. Un Conjunto no es igual a un Array. Decídete si vas a usar Conjuntos o Arrays.

Comment: Parece que la pregunta debería estar etiquetada como `JavaScript`, no parece tener relación con `TypeScript`, saludos

Comment: De hecho es Typescript lo que necesito pero Javascript sirve igual. 
Mauricio. Es irrelevante si es para conjuntos o arrays. Creo que la confusión es porque en Delphi los conjuntos se tratan igual con corchetes. La respuesta estuvo super bien. Tanto la de Felipe en su comentario como la Alfa Rojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En todo lenguaje de programación puedes implementarlo con algún tipo de ciclo, pero algunos ya traen una libreria implementada, javascript/typescript no son la excepción, te puedes guiar de la documentación [aqui descrita](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) pero básicamente existe el `.includes()` que toma como parametro el valor que quieres buscar en tu array, te dejo el ejemplo descrito en el link compartido

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2));
// Salida: true

const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];

console.log(pets.includes('cat'));
// Salida: true

console.log(pets.includes('at'));
// Salida: false
```

Luego de esto ya puedes jugar con los resultados

```
const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];
if(pets.includes('cat')){
    //Hacer algo si existe
    }
else{
    //Hacer algo si no existe
}
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias

Comment: @PedroSuárez Sii te sirvió, te agradecería si la marcas como al respuesta a tu pregunta, para que otras personas al encontrar tu pregunta, sepan que respuesta te ayudó, feliz día!!

Comment: Tu respuesta se basa en una estructura de Array, pero la pregunta, que no es del todo clara, habla de Conjuntos (en Delphi, [el operador `in` se aplica sobre Conjuntos](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=in)) o como los conocemos en Javascript: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Por favor, intenta mejorar tu respuesta y en todo caso, siempre es preferible pedir aclaraciones al OP antes de redactar una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: La respuesta está super bien. El problema es que en Delphi los conjuntos se tratan entre corchetes como los arreglos. Creo que ahí está su confusión